# For what is the following theorem about Dedekind domains useful?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, commutative-algebra

I am reading something about Dedekind domains and there was the following statement:

> Let $R$ be a Dedekind domain, then we have the following one to one correspondence $$\{\text{fractional ideals of }~R\}~~~\leftrightarrow~~~ \bigoplus_{0\neq p\subset R~\text{prime}} \Bbb{Z}$$given by $I\mapsto (v(p))_p$ and $\prod_p p^{(a_p)}\leftarrow (a_p)_p$

I somehow do not se for what this statement can be useful and also I don't see how to work with it. So for example if I take $R=\Bbb{Z}$ can I then find all the fractional ideals of $R$ using this statement?

Thanks for your help and clarification.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/137641/discussion-on-question-by-have-a-nice-day-for-what-is-the-following-theorem-abou).